# Is it possible to wait for an accept() using libaio?

Tags: c, linux

I am using libaio to do asynchronous IO.
I want to wait for a new client connecting to my TCP server.
Is it possible to wait for such an event using libaio?

There is IO_CMD_PREAD and IO_CMD_PWRITE but I did not see IO_CMD_PACCEPT...

Comment: libaio is more for *file* I/o, not other things like sockets. You want a `poll()`/`epoll`/etc. based approach.

Comment: I know about poll. I just wanted to try libaio. So your answer is that libaio does not support waiting for accept() to not block?